# Giving a class to a button and using javascript to pick up on th click event not working

Tags: php, javascript, html

Currently I have a button created:

```
<td><button class='ajax_button' data-id='4'>Reserve</button></td>
```

I also have a javascript section in the same file:

```
$(".ajax_button").click(function(){
     var temp = $(this).data("id");
     alert(temp);
});
```

The problem is when I click the button, the alert pop up does not show up.
What could I be doing wrong?

Also, I've noticed in javascript that there are different symbols in front of the.... $(#thing).click
$(.thing).click

The '#' and the '.', what is the difference?

Comment: you may want to add `jquery` to the tag list.

Answer (score 0):

The value that you pass to `$()` is a CSS selector. jQuery uses them to try and find elements on the page. In this case, it probably can't find your button, which is probably caused by the element not existing when you call `$()`.

You may be executing your javascript call too early. If you ask jQuery to select all elements with the class 'ajax_button', but none exist, then it can't add the onclick handler to anything, obviously. One way to solve this, is to wait for your entire page to be done loading. After that, add the click event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  // When the document is ready (DOM loaded)
    $(".ajax_button").click(function(){
        var temp = $(this).data("id");
        alert(temp);
    });
});
```

You can add multiple event handlers to the `ready` event of `document`, just like how you can add multiple `click` events on an element.

Note that, of course, any buttons created *after* the ready-state, won't get the click event. If you need that, read up on [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live)

Answer (score 0):

I had the javascript in the file that belonged where the ajax function was. I moved the javascript file to the correct file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Handling search results
    $('.ajax_button').click(function(e){
        // Get the name of the user clicked
        var lastName = $(this).data("lastName");
        var firstName = $(this).data("firstName");
        var phoneNum = $(this).data("phone");

        //alert('lastName'.value()' '.'firstName'.' '.'phoneNum');
        alert('hello');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The '#' and the '.', what is the difference?

The '#' is for selecting HTML object with specific id, eg:

```
$('#container')
```

will match with

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

and '.' is selector for HTML object that has specific class. eg:

```
$('.button')
```

will match with

```
<a class="button"></a>
<div class="button"></div>
```

If your button is created using javascript or ajax, the jquery `click` event function won't be attached to the element, use `live` event function, eg:

```
$('.ajax_button').live('click', function () {
    var temp = $(this).attr("data-id");
    alert(temp);
});
```